# select file in client when use citrix server in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog, citrix

I use citrix server for clients with c# win forms app.
in the client I want to select a file but the opendialogfile opens the server.
the openfiledialog automatically went to the drive of the server system but I want it goes to the client drive.

how can I access to the drive of client(current machine)?

Comment: You'll have to talk to the administrator of the Citrix system, and ask if your program can be given permission to do this. In general, the whole idea of systems like Citrix and other thin-client systems is to prevent programs from being dependent on the local machine or modifying the local machine.

Comment: Specifically the feature you need to be enabled is "Client Drive Mapping".